# How to remove child key from web to firebase using javascript code

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

These are my codes

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("User");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
var key = snap.key;
var name = snap.child("name").val();
var add = snap.child("address").val();
var contact = snap.child("contact").val();
$("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" +    name + "</td><td>" + add + "</td> 
<td>" + contact +  "</td><td>" + '<button onclick="reply_click(' + key + 
')">Delete</button></td></tr>');
 });

function reply_click(key){
firebase.database().ref("User").child(key).remove();
window.location.reload(key);    
}
```

i expect that if i click the delete button it will automatically deleted in firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try this by concatenating the key and removing it

```
firebase.database().ref('User/' + key).remove();
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting here? Can you share the DB structure?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is how you declare the HTML to be appended to the table (mixing-up single and double quotes). You should do as follows:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("User");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var key = snap.key;
    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var add = snap.child("address").val();
    var contact = snap.child("contact").val();
    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + add + "</td><td>" + contact +  "</td><td>" + "<button onclick=reply_click('" + key + "')>Delete</button></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: @Mimi Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?